# Use a top-level val with a function type as if it were a static function from Java

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-java-interop, kotlin-stdlib

A top-level `val` with a function type can be used like a "static" function from Kotlin, but is there a way to use it like a static function from Java as well?

---

For example, say we have a file called `Example.kt` that contains absolutely nothing besides this

```kotlin
val foo: (String) -> String = { s -> "Hello, $s" }
```

Using this in other Kotlin code works as you would expect in any functional language

```kotlin
foo("world")
```

Conceptually, this definition of `foo` is no different than the following Java code:

```java
public class ExampleKt {
  public static String foo(String s) { 
    return "Hello, " + s;
  }
}
```

However, if you actually have to call it from Java, it's pretty janky:

```java
ExampleKt.getFoo().invoke("world")
```

Desired behavior would be similar to how it can be used in Kotlin, like

```java
import static ExampleKt.foo;

foo("world");
```

In various other parts of the language, we can use `@JvmStatic` to make calling "static" kotlin code less janky from Java. Is there a way to do it here?

Comment: "we have a class called Example.kt" You mean we have a file with that name, right? I think the answer to your question is no, since the code you say is conceptually the same Java code is not actually conceptually the same. `foo` returns a function reference. You can use Kotlin's syntax to invoke the function reference concisely, but it is still a function reference that you just got from a property getter, not a direct call to a function of a class.

Comment: I guess the difference between Kotlin and some other languages is that you can’t just directly take a function’s name and pass it around like a reference. There is a distinction between `val foo` and `fun foo`. If it’s defined as a `fun`, you would have to convert it to a reference by using `::` before you could pass it around like an object.

Comment: Why not just declare it as a `fun` in Kotlin instead? I don't see the point of making `foo` a `val`.

Comment: @Sweeper in this silly example it really is pointless. But what if you are working with functions that return other functions? In that case it's often more convenient to assign to a `val` than a `fun`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Kotlin generally does a great job at masking what's going on behind the scenes, a lambda is not the same as a function in the JVM bytecode. It's true that conceptually, there's not many differences because Kotlin really leans into the whole "functions as first-class citizens" thing, but that's mostly just syntactic sugar.

For example, compare the bytecode output of an actual top-level function: https://godbolt.org/z/T7KK11ev7

and the bytecode of a top-level lambda `val`: https://godbolt.org/z/WP1j6WzzT

TL;DR the lambda `val` gets compiled to a Functor class (`ExampleKt$test$1`) which implements `kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0<kotlin.Unit>`. An instance of that class gets stored in a private static field of the `ExampleKt` class, with a corresponding static getter.

The compilation output is very reminiscent of how Java handles lambdas: They are essentially classes implementing a functional interface (like `Function`, `Consumer`, `Supplier`, ...), and everything else is syntactic sugar. It's just that Kotlin goes one step further and you can use function types instead of functional interfaces.

So I guess the answer to your question is no, there's no way to make this lambda seem like a static function in Java, unless you actually declare it as a `fun`. And `@JvmStatic` can't help here since your `val foo` already gets compiled to a static member, but it's a field and not a function.